# evaluate this region using gauss's theorem (only using the triple integral 'part')

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

> Evaluate 
>   $$\iiint _{D}\vec{\nabla} \cdot\vec{F}\,dV$$
>   with 
>   $$\vec{F}=\left \langle x^{2},y,z \right \rangle$$
>   $$D=\left \{ \left ( x,y,z \right )|x^{2}+y^{2}+1\leq z\leq 5 \right \}$$

$$\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{F}=2x+2$$

$$\int_{y=-2}^{2}\int_{-\sqrt{4-y^{2}}}^{+\sqrt{4-y^{2}}}\int_{x^{2}+y^{2}+1}^{5}2x+2\,dx\,dy\,dz $$

In polar, we have

$$\int_{\theta=0}^{2 \pi}\int_{r=0}^{2}\int_{r^{2}+1}^{5}\left ( 2 r \cos\theta +2\right )r\,dz\,dr\,d\theta$$

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35275/discussion-on-question-by-needhelp-evaluate-this-region-using-gausss-theorem-o).

Comment: That is a lot of work and unnecessary. What's $\nabla f$?

Comment: You can't be working on the divergence theorem and not know what the gradient is!

Comment: That's just 2x+2. I think you might have misunderstood. I'm trying to compute the flux across the closed surface. Not the divergence as is required in the triple integral.

Comment: Would appreciate if answer can be posted. Calling it a day. Spent too much time on a question.

Comment: I know what you're supposed to be doing. You have the wrong answer for gradient. I suggest that you look at similar problems in the text.

Comment: @OliverJones I do not understand. The gradient of a vector valued function is just $\frac{\partial x^{2}}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial z}$. If this is wrong, I don't know what is correct.
I am sure that the problem lies with the limit of intergration and/or the parameterisation. Will check back later. Too depressing to be hitting a brick wall for 2 whole hours

Comment: You took the divergence of the force field. I asked about the gradient of $f$. You clearly don't have a good grasp of the prerequisite material. Look at examples in your text.

Comment: The outward normal to the paraboloid is $(2x{\bf i}+2y{\bf j} -{\bf k})/\sqrt{4x^2+4y^2+1}$

Comment: @OliverJones I would like to look at the bigger picture here. I've looked through my text and also given that this is my third year in Uni, I cannot recall the role of grad of scalar f in the use of the flux across a closed surface in Gauss's theorem. 
I would like to know, kindly, where does this grad of f fits in to the entire schema.
This could be one of those 'tricky' problem types involving z as a surface integral and so z isn't a constant.
A waste to let this question go but I cannot brood over this forever-sometimes moving on is a better option.

Comment: @OliverJones
Evidently, the height of the paraboloid is described as a surface s by the graph of $z=f\left ( x,y \right )$
that is $x^{2}+y^{2}+1\leq f\left ( x,y \right )\leq 5$

If we let the parameterisation 
$\vec{X}\left ( x,y \right )=\left \langle x,y,f\left ( x,y \right ) \right \rangle$
then 
$\vec{N\left ( x,y \right )}=-f_{x}\hat{i}-f_{y}\hat{j} + \hat{k}$
as the outward pointing standard normal vector.

The unit normal vector is $\hat{n}=\frac{\vec{N}}{\left \| \vec{N} \right \|}$

Comment: What you're saying here is basically correct. But normals are of the form $\pm \hat{n}$. You have to choose the sign that makes it outward. For the paraboloid you need $- \hat{n}$. Check your text to see where gradients are covered. One application is calculating normals to surfaces. It's often the case that you don't need to parameterize with something different to $x$ and $y$. If your instructor didn't spend significant time discussing the gradient then he/she is incompetent.

Comment: The standard normal given by me is the conventional upward pointing one. But upward for a paraboloid implies that the normal points in the direction to the 'inside' of the paraboloid. So, negating the above standard normal vector, we arrive at the standard normal given by you.
How should I think about the limit of integration in this case? The limit of integration for the 'cap' or a circular surface and that is easy.@OliverJones

Comment: It not upwards, it's outwards and it depends entirely on the configuration. You should always sketch the region so that you get the orientation correct. For the surface integral, you need to convert it to a double integral in the $(x,y)$-plane. There's a formula for that.

Comment: @OliverJones I think I'd sort of figure it out-at least intuitively how I ought to go about doing it. Thanks for your dedication and patience!

Comment: You're welcome. There are a ton of examples online and in texts and the approach is standard.